# how to delete all entries of table_x using trigger which is fired by table_y

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `back_up_data` BEFORE UPDATE ON `admin`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE x FLOAT;
IF NEW.sem_completed=1 THEN
SET x=update_cgpa();
TRUNCATE notifications;
TRUNCATE course_offerings;
TRUNCATE takes;
SET NEW.sem_completed=0;
UPDATE students SET current_sem=(current_sem+1);
IF OLD.current_semester=0 THEN
    SET NEW.current_year=OLD.current_year+1;
    SET NEW.current_semester=1;
ELSE
    SET NEW.current_semester=0;
END IF; 
END IF;

END
```

When I try to run this code, I'm getting the following error:
**Can't create a stored procedure from within another  stored routine**

Comment: Odd you should be getting errors relating to the truncate statements (which aren't allowed in triggers) ERROR 1422 (HY000): Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger. - use delete instead.

Comment: Thanks it worked!!. I wonder why truncate is not working here

Comment: because a truncate has an implied commit...